# magento - cloning webshop results in http500 - PHP fatal error

Tags: php, magento, fatal-error, magento-1.6

i am trying to clone my webshop again for a test environment.
(magento 1.6.2 on a dedicated server)

I never had any trouble doing this.
I just deleted all the old content in FTP and DB and then i make a copy of the live store and synchronize the db.

Then i change the url in the db and the test-db in the local.xml.

I also clean the var/cache and var/session.

This always worked well.

But yesterday did the same ... but now i get a http 500 error. (white screen)

From the error logs:
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 222 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1"

and

PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getCode() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/liefstoereigenwijs.nl/testwinkel/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php on line 701

I tried to use the magento-cleanup.php and i also changed all permissions to 775. 
But all without result ...

Has anyone have a clue?

UPDATE:
In the system.log i see the following errors:

2012-07-10T12:33:53+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Core_Model_Store_Group::setWebsite() must be an instance of Mage_Core_Model_Website, null given, called in /var/www/vhosts/liefstoereigenwijs.nl/testwinkel/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php on line 648 and defined  in /var/www/vhosts/liefstoereigenwijs.nl/testwinkel/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store/Group.php on line 235
2012-07-10T12:33:53+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: 1  in /var/www/vhosts/liefstoereigenwijs.nl/testwinkel/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php on line 701

Comment: What's the output if you insert `Zend_Debug::dump($this->_stores); die;` just before line 701?

Comment: i get the same error ... even if i put a extra line between, it keeps talking about line 701 - it seems there is some sort of cache somewhere ... because i don't have the idea its updated ...

Comment: And the URL in the browser doesn't change? That would hint to a problem with your base urls in core_config_data. Does the same error occur when you comment the line out? It really sounds like some sort of cache problem. Are you absolutely sure you're working in the right environment? (Try putting a `die` statement at the beginning of your root index.php) Does the PHP error appear in the browser or in a /var/report/xxxxxxxx file?

Comment: in the systemlog i have some extra errors i see. The var/report remains empty ... Further i haven't changed any environment ... and the live shop works well

Comment: Have a look at your core_store table.. What store_ids do you find there?

Comment: it's empty - i have imported the data from the live store - no result ...

Comment: Something must have gone wrong when you copied the database. This table should have at least two rows (admin and default). Other tables have probably faild too. Have you tried deleting the entire database and cloning from your production site again? See if the two entries are missing again.

Comment: there must some sort of cache ... i have deleted the old test db and made a new one with other credentials ... i haven't changed the local.xml yet, so my demo site can't access the db ... but my error are still the same ... i already restarted the server ... without any luck ...

Comment: The only cache I know of i var/cache... but you said you already emptied that..

Comment: then it must be a system related cache/memory problem ....

Comment: ...or the problem occurs before Magento even tries to access the database. Have you tried putting a die statement right at the beginning of your index.php file?

Comment: i have made a new clone with a other domain - the var/cache is empty but i see a db core_cache_tag with more than 12000 lines. do you think i should delete all of these lines?

Comment: I don't know what this table does, but it's empty in my installation. I'd make a backup of the table's data and empty it, yes.

Comment: i got it ... i flushed all cache ... i guess memcache or varnish was the problem. Thank you for your help

Comment: Congratulations. :) You're very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memcache and/or Varnish cache were the problem.

I fushed all caches in the live store, and that was the solution for me.

Comment: But here i can't access admin panel and i also deleted var/cache.